# VSCode java how do I set the path for the compiled .class files to go?

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, .class-file

I'm using the Java Test Runner extension in VScode, and I want it to compile my classes to a specific folder. I found the setting to change the -cp when actually running the compiled .class files, but the whole thing still fails since the extension builds the .class files in an obscure temporary folder deep in it's appdata folder.

I would like it to compile my .java classes into a folder I have within my project, so that I can have them there. I have tried googling the sh*t out of this and either I have no idea what I'm saying or noone has ever had a problem with this before.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 4):

This is a late answer, but I just ran into this so I hope it helps others.

As of Feb 4, 2021 there is now a setting for the [Java Language Support for VS Code extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=redhat.java), where you can specify the output directory for compiled .class files. If you're using VS Code to run Java I'm almost certain you'd have this extension installed.

Simply open your VS Code settings and search for `java.project.outputPath`. As you'll notice, it states this setting only applies for Workspace settings, **not** User settings. So make sure to switch to the Workspace tab before clicking `Edit in settings.json`. This will edit the `settings.json` file in your projects `.vscode` folder.

[image]

Also note this doesn't work for projects managed with Maven/Gradle. It's great for simple projects though.

For the curious: link to the GitHub pull request where the feature was added to the extension (also has a neat gif of feature in action): https://github.com/redhat-developer/vscode-java/pull/1694

Answer (score 0):

https://blog.usejournal.com/visual-studio-code-for-java-the-ultimate-guide-2019-8de7d2b59902

Under "Adding Libraries and JARs"

Comment: While this is an excellent link filled with very good tips for configuring VS Code for use with Java, it does not directly address the OP' question (`the extension builds the .class files in an obscure temporary folder deep in it's appdata folder`).  The OP would like to know how to specify the output/target folder.  When using Maven, for example, pom.xml contains these details.  However, unless you use Maven, Gradle, and others, there doesn't seem to be a way to switch from the default appdata output folder. 
 One can compile from the Terminal, but that too is not what the OP requested.

Answer (score 0):

First of all,
you can create a CLASSPATH location in your environment variable section, after you set your path location.

Also, what people usually mistake is that they install a code runner used to compile and run all the languages, so if you are running your java code through the top-right run button,
then click on the drop down menu beside it and click the "run java" button and I guess then your code will run just fine.(if you have downloaded java runner extension separately)

I hope this helps!