# How do make the vscode create .class files in the same folder of my java file?

Tags: java, visual-studio-code

I am using java extension pack by Microsoft in vscode.

Whenever I click on **run** or **debug** the *.class* file in created in some different folder which is hard to track.
This is what happens when I click on *run java*
`e:; cd 'e:\DAA_JAVA\lab_internal'; & 'c:\Users\User\.vscode\extensions\vscjava.vscode-java-debug-0.35.0\scripts\launcher.bat' 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-16.0.1\bin\java.exe' '--enable-preview' '-XX:+ShowCodeDetailsInExceptionMessages' '-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8' '-cp' 'C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Code\User\workspaceStorage\8f978c532d0fff698dd5ae65e10feb26\redhat.java\jdt_ws\lab_internal_a739e7\bin' 'Mergesort'`

I request the open community to help me to create the *.class* files in the same folder where my .java file is contained.

Thank you

Comment: why would you do that? and what is 'hard to track' about it? if you want it in the same directory, don't use an IDE

Comment: Does this answer your question? [VSCode java how do I set the path for the compiled .class files to go?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63583862/vscode-java-how-do-i-set-the-path-for-the-compiled-class-files-to-go)

Comment: how do I set the _java.project.OutputPath_ to my current path of my directory.
Basically , whenever I click on run from vscode the .class file has to be created in my current directory.
Is there any way to do that?
Thank you

Comment: @PravinPK: could you explain **why** you would like to change the default position? There are good reasons behind the setting and .class files should not usually live right next to .java file (or where you happen to run the code from). I think you have an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info) and would get better help if you explained what the underlying issue is that you're trying to solve.

Comment: Press **Ctrl+,** to open Settings, click the option `Workspace` and search `java.project.outputPath`, then edit in Settings.json. Like @Shengchen answered, set a relative path of the output folder.

Comment: Replying to @JoachimSauer, I am a college student, sometimes as a part of assignments we have to submit the  _.java_ file along with _.class_ file. And it was a drag to go through that long path to get _.class_ files.
Ya as MollyWang-MSFT said I can set path, but every time I work on new project I have to set a new relative path right which points to my working folder. I don't want to do this manually every time. I want vscode to make _.class_ files in my current working directory for all the new projects I open with different directories.
Thanks

Comment: @PravinPK. It indeed does. if I create a no build tools project then open `App.java`, after building the project, there will be a folder `bin` generated in current workspace and `App.class` is there even though I don't run the .java file. Please update your java extension, especially **Project Manager**. If not work, try [VS Code Insiders](https://code.visualstudio.com/insiders/) and folder `bin` is also generated in it.

Comment: Thanks @MollyWang-MSFT. But the problem is it was not creating in VS code.
I will try VS code insiders
Anyways thanks for the help

Comment: @PravinPK. Have you tried the settings mentioned in the answer below?

Comment: @MollyWang-MSFT , yes I did, but every time I work on different project I need to specify  new path every single time. I don't want all my project's class files to be in same folder. Each project much have its own directories of class files. And moreover I am not used to workspace of VS code , have to work on it more.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are developing in a project without build tools (no Maven/Gradle)

In that case, you can use the setting `java.project.outputPath` to set a relative path of the output folder

> Note: this setting only works in the WORKSPACE scope, please do not set it in the USER scope.

Comment: I notice that if I create a no build tools project then open `App.java`, after building the project, there will be a folder `bin` generated and `App.class` is there even though I don't run the .java file. It's also achievable in **VS Code Insiders** but didn't occur before in VS Code, is this a new feature? I'm using **Language Support for Java(TM) by Red Hat v0.80.0**.

Comment: We make a change in the Project Manager extension: when creating a no build tool project, we will preset the setting. (You can find it in the .vscode/settings.json) file.